# Android: Uploading images to server using fragments and navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Initially I made an app that uploads photos to a php server using **Activity** and **ListActivity**. Now I am switching the same app to **fragments** using **navigation drawer**.

I managed to do like this:

[image: Navigation image][image: Gallery Image]

I made a java class extending **Fragment** called **MyGalleryFragment** and is like this:

```
public class MyGalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    public ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    Context context;

    public MyGalleryFragment() {}

    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    public String imgPath = null;
    String upLoadServerUri = "http://www.jhamel.com/print/UploadToServer.php";

    SessionMngr session;

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHypens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    TextView tvMulMsg;

    private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = container.getContext();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_image_grid, container, false);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

        Cursor imagecursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                orderBy);

        this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

            System.out.println("=====> Array path => "+imageUrls.get(i));
        }

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context, imageUrls);


        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        imageLoader.stop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void btnChoosePhotosClick(View v){

        final ArrayList<String> selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Uploading file...",true);
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            UploadFile(selectedItems);
        }
        }).start();
            }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        ArrayList<String> mList;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context mContext;
        SparseBooleanArray msparseBooleanArray;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
            mContext = context;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            msparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
            mList = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.mList = imageList;
            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems(){
            ArrayList<String> mTempArray = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<mList.size();i++){
                if(msparseBooleanArray.get(i)){
                    mTempArray.add(mList.get(i));
                }
            }
            return mTempArray;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) { //argument is position
            return null;
        }
        @Override 
        public long getItemId(int position) { //argument is position
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);
            }

            CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            final ImageView imageView =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+imageUrls.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
                    imageView.setAnimation(anim);
                    anim.start();
                }
            });

            mCheckBox.setTag(position);
            mCheckBox.setChecked(msparseBooleanArray.get(position));
            mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

            return convertView;
        }
        OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                msparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
            }
        };
    }


    protected int UploadFile(ArrayList<String> sourceFileUri){

        ConnectionMngr cm = new ConnectionMngr(context);
        boolean connection = cm.hasConnection();
        if(!connection){
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection. Please connect to the internet and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return 0;
        }

        String fileName;// = sourceFileUri.get(2).toString();

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        File sourceFile = null;

            try{
                // Open a URL connection to the Servelet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); //Sets connection method
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");                  
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

                for(int i=0 ; i<sourceFileUri.size() ; i++){

                    sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri.get(i));
                    //boolean flag = _ifIsFile(sourceFile);

                    if(!_ifIsFile(sourceFile)){
                        return 0;
                    }

                    fileName = sourceFile.toString();
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    //conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file[]", fileName);

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHypens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file[]\";filename=\"" + fileName+"\""+lineEnd);
                    //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uid\";filename=\"" + "rabin"+"\""+lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while(bytesRead>0){
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    //dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHypens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uid\";value=\"" + "rabin shrestha" +"\""+lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                }
                // send multipart form data necessary after file data
                dos.writeBytes(twoHypens+boundary+twoHypens+lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server(code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile","HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){ //if http response is created
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.";
                            //tvMulMsg.setText(msg);
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();

                        }
                    });
                }
                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss(); 
                ex.printStackTrace();

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tvMulMsg.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        //Toast.makeText(Gallery.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss(); 
                e.printStackTrace();

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tvMulMsg.setText("Got Exception with server");
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Got Exception with server ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e); 
            }
            dialog.dismiss();      
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

    public boolean _ifIsFile(File file){
        if(!file.isFile()){
            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist : " + imgPath);

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvMulMsg.setText("Source File not exist : " + imgPath);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

and a **Dashboard** class like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {


    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new MyGalleryFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MyGalleryFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MyGalleryFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new MyGalleryFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new MyGalleryFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;
        case 9:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;
        case 10:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;
        case 11:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;
        case 12:
            fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if(position>=5){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        if(fragment != null){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                            .commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }else{
        Intent i = new Intent(Dashboard.this, MyGallery.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

also I have a repo on git you can fork that [here](https://github.com/robzStha/Photoprint_v1_1/tree/master).

I managed to get fragments and is able to display the images from the mobile gallery but now when i tried to upload the images it throws errors

Stack Trace:

```
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): Process: jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1, PID: 2620
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnChoosePhotosClick(View) in the activity class jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1.Dashboard for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: btnChoosePhotosClick [class android.view.View]
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
03-21 04:06:19.033: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     ... 11 more
```

I want to upload the images and **btnChoosePhotosClick** method is called when **Upload Selected** button is clicked. **btnChoosePhotosClick** method is there in **MyGalleryFragment** class but it seeks from next activity i.e Dashboard. You can view the files in [github](https://github.com/robzStha/Photoprint_v1_1/blob/master/src/jsoft/projects/photoprint_v1_1/Dashboard.java).

if you had downloaded the project than the **username : password** for the app is **test:test**

I am new to Android and also fragment is very new to me.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not find a method btnChoosePhotosClick(View) in the activity class jsoft.projects.photoprint_v1_1.Dashboard for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
```

You have to create the method btnChoosePhotosClick(View) in Dashboard.java. I don't like call methods from layout, I prefer do something like that:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btnChoosePhotosClick(v);
}
});
```